# How could we use angular js components names in html

Tags: angularjs

My doubt is simple, I have a component called pm-legend and I have a HTML file named legend.html.

```
my component code is like this,
.component('pmLegend', {
bindings: {
  fullLegend: '<',
  summary: '<'
},
template: require('./legend.html'),
controller: legendComponent
```

My doubt: How it is taking the component name as pm-legend and we have named 
our component as pmLegend.
How can I use 'pm-legend' in my HTML instead of 'pmLegend'
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go through https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component then you will understand what is happening with your code.

Comment: Thanks! I got some idea.